# Axios post request works on Postman but not on browser (it returns "Error 401- Not Authorized")

Tags: node.js, express, axios, postman, mern

I'm having a problem with an axios post request. In the browser, if I check "Network" in the console, it displays the error "401 - Not authorized". But doing tests with Postman everything works perfectly.
I have already tried several solutions exposed in similar questions but without success.

This is the code where I set up the express server:

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import authRouter from "./routes/auth.js";
import categoryRouter from "./routes/category.js";

//DOTENV CONFIG
dotenv.config();
const MONGODB_CONNECTION = process.env.MONGO_URI;

//INITIALIZE APP
const app = express();

//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

//ROUTES
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRouter);

//PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5020;

//CONNECT MONGODB
const connectDB = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_CONNECTION, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("MONGODB is connected"))
    .catch((err) => console.log("MONGODB connection error:", err));
};

connectDB();

//INITIALIZE SERVER
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Connection is established and running on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

This is the code related to the setting of the routers:

```js
import express from "express";
import { getCategories, createCategory } from "../controllers/category.js";
import { authMiddleware, authAdminMiddleware } from "../middlewares/auth.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/get-categories").get(getCategories);
router
  .route("/create-category")
  .post(authMiddleware, authAdminMiddleware, createCategory);

export default router;
```

Middlewares for authentication:

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { User } from "../models/User.js";

dotenv.config();
const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

export const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token;
    if (
      req.headers.authorization &&
      req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
    ) {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    }

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ errorMessage: "Invalid Authentication" });
    }

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    const user = await User.findById(decoded.user._id);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ errorMessage: "No user found" });
    }

    req.user = user;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: "Not authorized" });
  }
};

export const authAdminMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      _id: req.user.id,
    });
    if (req.user.role === 0) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Not Authorized. Admin private route." });
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ errorMessage: "Not Authorized. Admin private route." });
  }
};
```

POST request controller:

```js
import { Category } from "../models/Category.js";
import slugify from "slugify";

export const createCategory = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, parentId } = req.body;

  try {
    if (!name) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Category name field is required." });
    }

    const category = await Category.findOne({ name });

    if (category) {
      return res.status(409).json({ errorMessage: "Category already exist." });
    }

    let id;

    if (parentId) {
      const findParentId = await Category.findOne({ name: parentId });
      if (findParentId) {
        id = findParentId._id;
      }
    }

    const newCategory = new Category({
      name,
      slug: slugify(name),
      parentId: id,
    });
    newCategory.save((err, saved) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
      }
      if (saved) {
        return res
          .status(201)
          .json({ successMessage: "Category created successfully!" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: error.message });
  }
};
```

API calls on front-end:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { getCookies } from "../helpers/storage&cookies/storage&cookies";

console.log(getCookies("token"));

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + getCookies("token"),
  },
};

export const postCategory = async (data) => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:5020/api/categories/create-category",
    data,
    config
  );
  return response;
};
```

Specific client-side post request:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CreateCategoryModalUI from "./CreateCategoryModalUI";
import { postCategory } from "../../../api/category";

const CreateCategoryModal = ({ categories }) => {
  const [createCategoryData, setCreateCategoryData] = useState({
    name: "",
    parentId: "",
    errorMessage: "",
    successMessage: "",
    loading: false,
  });

  const { name, parentId, successMessage, errorMessage, loading } =
    createCategoryData;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type == "text") {
      setCreateCategoryData({
        ...createCategoryData,
        name: e.target.value,
        successMessage: "",
        errorMessage: "",
      });
    } else {
      setCreateCategoryData({
        ...createCategoryData,
        parentId: e.target.value,
        errorMessage: "",
        successMessage: "",
      });
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!name) {
      setCreateCategoryData({
        ...createCategoryData,
        errorMessage: "Category name field is required.",
      });
    } else {
      const data = { name, parentId };
      console.log(data);
      setCreateCategoryData({
        ...createCategoryData,
        loading: true,
      });

      postCategory(data)
        .then((response) => {
          setCreateCategoryData({
            name: "",
            parentId: "",
            errorMessage: "",
            successMessage: response.data.successMessage,
            loading: false,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.status === 409) {
            setCreateCategoryData({
              ...createCategoryData,
              errorMessage: "Category already exists",
              loading: false,
            });
          } else {
            setCreateCategoryData({
              ...createCategoryData,
              errorMessage: error.toString(),
              loading: false,
            });
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <CreateCategoryModalUI
      createCategoryData={createCategoryData}
      categories={categories}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
    />
  );
};

export default CreateCategoryModal;
```

How can I fix that?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Use your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel to check the request. Does it have the correct bearer token in the `Authorization` header? Also, you don't need to manually set CORS response headers if you're using the `cors` package

Comment: Yes, I've already checked: the Authorization header is correct.
Moreover I had set the CORS response headers also manually due to the fact that  for another POST request I had had similar problems, solved, inexplicably, by adding those two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so, that's why I'm posting as an answer.

You could try to set withCredentials to true when you create an Axios instance, withCredentials does the following acording to Axios repository:

> `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests
> should be made using credentials

The official documentation doesn't add any further explanation...

```js
axios.create({ withCredentials: true, })
```

Comment: OP is using bearer tokens which does not require `withCredentials`

Comment: Thanks, I also tried with {withCredentials: true}, but despite having set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to my client localhost address, I got this error:  "Access to XMLHttpRequest at  ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I solved! The problem, as often happens to me, was an oversight. Specifically, in the authentication middleware.
In these lines of code:

> const user = await User.findById (decoded.user._id)

I added a superfluous 'user' after 'decoded', but the object key was simply '_id'.